# Creality Ender 3 Max won't print after homing

Tags: creality-ender-3, ultimaker-cura

After successfully printing for a while with my Ender 3 Max I've encountered a problem I can't solve. The printer executes the heating and homing portion of the G-code after which it just sits in the middle (I have BLTouch installed, so homing ends in the middle). The print percentages go up (much quicker than they should) and the print "finishes". No filament is extruded and the head doesn't move at all.

What I've tried:

- Different SD cards,
- Checked the new G-code to make sure it doesn't only have the beginning and end,
- Old G-code that worked the previous day,
- Made sure that all axes, filament change, and purge work fine from the prepare menu,
- Releveled the bed from the BLTouch leveling section from the control menu.

Everything but printing seems fine and now I'm stumped.